# Flutter: MissingPluginException since multidex achieved

Tags: android, flutter, android-multidex

Since my app achieved multidex I start getting the next error:

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/package_info)
```

I have `package_info` package in my dependencies, actually it works just fine before I added `facebook` package.

I also updated my `gradle` file with next code:

```
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dependencies { 
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    }
```

properties here:

```
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

but it still doesn't work. I have a feeling that it might be cos the `package_info` related code is not in the main dex. Can it be true?
Anyway, any ideas on how it might be fixed?

Comment: A comment on a repo suggests upgrading flutter. might help. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65334#issuecomment-703434060

Comment: @Prathik `FlutterActivity` already contain that part, so nope... (

Comment: @JaswantSingh nope...

Comment: Are you on the latest stable version of flutter?

Comment: I have an exactly same problem and struggling for days and none of solution worked for me so far...

Comment: Just found it causes the error after importing flutter_facebook_auth package.

Answer (score 0):

[Andriy Antonov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6674369/andriy-antonov), I had this issue after upgrading `flutter to 1.24 stable channel`, and this issue gone for me after updating the package to the latest version:

```
package_info: ^0.4.3+2
```

Comment: I already updated it to the last one. As I said - it was working fine until multidex comes...

Comment: Run `flutter clean` then rebuild!